# Condition to render different templates in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox, lightning-radiogroup

I have a problem with a condition, in a LWC.
I have an array of addresses. If the array has only one element, I should display a radio button. If the array has more than 1 element, than I should display a combobox.

I've wrote the fuction to check the length of my array and passed it to my templates condition. Something simillar with the below code:

```
@track addressList =[ {street:"121 Spear St.", city:"San Francisco", country:"US", province:"CA", postalCode:"94105", id : "12344", name:"home"},
                        {street:"321 Mall St.", city:"New York", country:"US", province:"NY", postalCode:"13211", id : "78545", name:"work"},
                        {street:"534 Port St.", city:"Miami", country:"US", province:"FL", postalCode:"06107", id : "77474", name:"parents home"}
                     ];

@api
    isSingleAddress() {
        return this.addressList.length == 1;
    }
```

On the HTML component I have the following code:

```
<template if:false={isSingleAddress}>
        <lightning-combobox
                name="name"
                label="BILLING ADDRESS"
                options={options}
                value={value}
                onchange={handleChange}>
        </lightning-combobox>
</template>

<template if:true={isSingleAddress}>
    <lightning-radio-group label="BILLING ADDRESS"
                           options={options}
                           value={value}
                           type="radio">
    </lightning-radio-group>
</template>
```

The problem that I'm facing is that even if I have a single element array, it will display something like this:

[image]

Can someone help me with some hints, please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
@api
get isSingleAddress() {
    return this.addressList.length == 1;
}
```

`if:true` and `if:false` check for [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) properties/attributes, and so will not call functions.

A function is truthy:

```
if(function() {}) {
  console.log('is true!')
}
```

And so `is:true` will always consider a function as true, and `if:false` will never consider a function as false.

Comment: This solve my issue! Thanks a lot @sfdcfox !